# systemd deletes sub-cgroups started by other services

Tags: systemd, cgroup, condor

I have a service (HTCondor batch system), which is started as service unit within cpu,cpuacct and memory cgroup slices (CentOS 7 @ 3.10.0-*).

The service starts sub-processes (~~> batch jobs) for which it creates sub-slices, i.e., subdividing its parent resources. Without further interfering, the started processes are in the sub-slices

```
wc -l /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/condor.service/tasks
  19
wc -l /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/condor.service/*/tasks
  29 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/condor.service/condor_var_lib_condor_execute_slot1_2@batch0311.desy.de/tasks
  22 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/condor.service/condor_var_lib_condor_execute_slot1_3@batch0311.desy.de/tasks
  22 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/condor.service/condor_var_lib_condor_execute_slot1_4@batch0311.desy.de/tasks
  ...
```

and as cross-check, the processes have their corresponding cgroups also in their process info, e.g.,

```
cat /proc/58683/cgroup 
  11:perf_event:/
  10:memory:/system.slice/condor.service/condor_var_lib_condor_execute_slot1_6@batch0311.desy.de
  9:devices:/system.slice
  8:blkio:/system.slice/condor.service     /condor_var_lib_condor_execute_slot1_6@batch0311.desy.de
  7:cpuset:/
  6:freezer:/system.slice/condor.service/condor_var_lib_condor_execute_slot1_6@batch0311.desy.de
  5:hugetlb:/
  4:cpuacct,cpu:/system.slice/condor.service/condor_var_lib_condor_execute_slot1_6@batch0311.desy.de
  3:pids:/system.slice/condor.service
  2:net_prio,net_cls:/
  1:name=systemd:/system.slice/condor.service
```

AFAIS, systemd seems to be not aware of the sub-slices as systemd-cgls shows the processes directly beneath the the parent unit's cgroup

```
systemd-cgls
   ...
   ├─condor.service
   │ ├─  781 /bin/bash ...foo...
   │ ├─ 1596 condor_starter -f -a slot1_4 ...baz...
```

Now, when adding a new unit, reloading the systemd daemons and starting the new unit, all the job sub-cgroups disappear and their processes get attached to the parent cgroup.

```
wc -l /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/condor.service/tasks
  337 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/condor.service/tasks
```

My assumption is, that systemd is not aware of the sub-slices (guessing from systemd-cgls), while from the kernel's view these are proper cgroup slices. When starting the new unit, systemd notices the discrepancy from its expectations and 'cleans up'.

Can this behaviour somehow be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like upstream since fixed this by specifying the `Delegate=` directive (commit [890186d82a](https://github.com/htcondor/htcondor/commit/890186d82af98dc27c505af2aa68a8a1f5baa837) – though specifying a subset of controllers would be a bit more elegant than simply `true` IMHO). If that update isn’t propagated to the CentOS package, you can apply it locally with the following command:

```
systemctl set-property condor.service Delegate=true
```

Answer (score 1):

problem was, that by default systemd assumes that all sub-cgroup/slices are handled by itself and that any unit processes have no own control.

When enabling delegation for a unit, systemd will not try to take control of the unit's sub-resources

```
[Service]
...
Delegate=true
```

(the [Slice] section might also be the right section, but apparently the right section depends on the release/kernel so #YMMV)

note that the cgroups/slices shown by
  systemd-cgls
and
  systemd-cgtop
still differ and only systemd-cgtop shows the 'right'Ä kernel view of cgroups while systemd-cgls does not show any sub-hierarchy of slices even with delegation)